# How can posterior be persisted and reconstituted as future prior?

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, hierarchical-bayesian, bayes

Suppose I model a data generating process as a hierarchal model and have made some training observation from the process.   To learn about the process, with the observations I run the bayesian machinery to calculate posterior for the  stochastic parameters of the model.  Now I would like to be able to throw out the observations and just use the posterior I got in the learning process as prior for learning from the next set of observations.

For cases where I don't have conjugate prior story, I am not sure how one can persist the state of posterior  (while throwing away all your observations) so that it can be used as prior for the next observation?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You don't absolutely *need* a conjugate prior; it just makes your life considerably easier. For any probability distribution(s), it is true that
$$ P(\textrm{A } | \textrm{ B}) = \frac{P(\textrm{B } | \textrm{ A}) \cdot P(\textrm{A})}{P(\textrm{B})}$$

However, a conjugate prior helps in two ways:

1. It can be messy--and difficult to do the updating for two arbitrary distributions. There often may not be a closed form solution, which means you'll have to fiddle around with potentially complicated and inexact numerical solutions.
2. It simplifies the interpretation. Suppose you have a normal likelihood function and a normal prior. The resulting distribution is also a normal distribution. After several rounds of updating, you could then make well-supported claims about the mean and variance. This is often useful. On the other hand, if your end goal is to be able to use your fitted $P(A|B)$ to calculate $P(A'|B)$ for some new data $A'$, then maybe you would not care too much.

There is a handy [Compendium of Conjugate Priors](http://www.johndcook.com/CompendiumOfConjugatePriors.pdf), compiled by Daniel Fink, that might help you find one that matches your likelihood function.